# document.getElementById not working even if I ve ID present in my css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried searching but didnt get a valid answer to my question. 
I always get "null" when I call `document.getElementById("#"+id)` and it alerts `Document not loaded`.

My Javascript code

```
function changeDisplay(id) {
    alert("#"+id);

    if (!document.getElementById("#"+id)) {
        alert("Document Not loaded");
    } else {

        if (id == "property_photos") {
            alert(id);
            document.getElementById("#property_photos").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("#property_details").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("#property_reviews").style.display = "none";
            alert(document.getElementById(id).style.display);
        }
        if (id == "property_details") {
            alert(id);
            document.getElementById("#property_photos").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("#property_details").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("#property_reviews").style.display = "none";
            alert(document.getElementById(id).style.display);
        }
        if (id == "property_reviews") {
            alert(id);
            document.getElementById("#property_photos").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("#property_details").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("#property_reviews").style.display = "block";
            alert(document.getElementById(id).style.display);

        }
    }
}
```

The HTML

```
<li>
    <a href="#property_photos" onclick="changeDisplay('property_photos')">Photos</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#property_details" onclick="changeDisplay('property_details')">Details</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#property_reviews" onclick="changeDisplay('property_reviews')">Reviews</a>
</li>
```

The CSS

```
#property_photos {
    display:none;
}
#property_details {
    display:block;
}
#property_reviews {
    display:none;
}
```

Any help would be grateful. Its a simple question. I got the same code to work on different page but not in page m working on. I have even called .css file before defining the function but the error persists.

Comment: You don't need the pound sign `#`. Perhaps you have been using jQuery a lot? I know I've made the same mistake before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` does *not* need the pound (#) symbol.

Answer (score 1):

While you're using JavaScript, you don't use `#` sign to reference the ID of the element.

Your code for

```
alert("#"+id);
```

Would be

```
alert(id);
```

You need `#` Number sign, only when working with CSS or jQuery.