# document.getElementById("#foo"); returns null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a media player.

I am not sure why my call to `document.getElementById("#playlist-table");` returns null when I have in my HTML `<table id="playlist-table"></table>`. I have tried running the script just before the `</body>` tag to make sure the DOM was ready, and still no luck. Here is my code:

**HTML**(shortened)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en"> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>JAMTRACKS</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="media-player">
        <div id="playlist">
            <table id="playlist-table"></table>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**JS**(shortened)

```
  function addTrack(title){
    var table = document.getElementById("#playlist-table");
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var titleTd = document.createElement("td");
    var titleNode = document.createTextNode("title");

    table.appendChild(tr);    //ERROR IS HERE

    tr.appendChild(titleTd);
    titleTd.appendChild(titleNode);
    ...
  }
  addTrack(Song_Name);
```

**Error** : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [document.getElementById not working even if I ve ID present in my css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345026/document-getelementbyid-not-working-even-if-i-ve-id-present-in-my-css)

Answer (score 3):

remove the hashtag `#` from the selector

`var table = document.getElementById("playlist-table");`

if you want to keep it, you should use [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
document.querySelector('#playlist-table')
```

Comment: Thank you but I am still having trouble. I even tried to create a simple <p> element filled with text and had no success ... I am new to all this.

    `var p = document.createElement("p");
    var hi = document.createTextNode("Hi");
    p.appendChild(hi);
    document.body.appendChild(p);`

I get the same error on line 4. "Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"

Comment: Your DOM isn't ready when you do that. Try putting your code below the body or use an `onLoad()` event handler.

Comment: This worked. Earlier, I must not have been doing the onload stuff correctly. I just moved the link to my js to after the body. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Correct ways to query for id:

`document.getElementById('foo');`

or

`document.querySelectorAll('#foo');`

Returns the first element:

`document.querySelector('#foo');`

Answer (score 2):

^^

var table = document.getElementById("playlist-table");